# export specialized template function from a dll

Tags: c++, templates, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I have a template function that I define in a header file in a dll. I don't need to export the function because all of the consumers will read in the header file and have the whole function anyway. However, I have a specialization of that template that can't be defined in the header file (or I will get redefinition linker errors), so it has to go in the source file.

What is the normal way to export this function?

```
template <typename T>
bool functionName(/*params*/){
//.....
}

template<> IMPORTEXPORTMACRO
bool functionName(/*params*/);
```

and the source file has

```
template<>
bool functionName(/*params*/){
//...
```

`IMPORTEXPORTMACRO` is one of those macros that is either `__declspec(dllimport)` or `dllexport`

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just make the specialized function inline? Thus avoiding the header errors.

Comment: then i get errors from the function being defined multiple times.

Comment: Can you show your code briefly (You don't need to show the whole implementation or anything).  When I say inline you are specifying the `inline` right?

Comment: @bdwain : You won't if you actually mark the function as `inline`, i.e. decorate it with the `inline` keyword.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fVyJdt33

the first 2 things are in the header, and the last one is in the source file

Comment: is there an easy way to paste code in here? their thing was giving me trouble.

Comment: the inline thing worked but i'd rather not make it inline if possible

Comment: @bdwain:  Read this it will explain why templates need to be in header files.  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12

Comment: i understand that but template specializations don't need to, do they?

Comment: @bdwain I added in your pastebin code to the question. To make code formatted nice on stackoverflow, select the code and press CTRL+k, or just add at least 4 spaces before each line in the code.

Comment: @bdwain: Template specializations need to be declared in a header, they can then be defined in a single implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

template things are indeed place holders. Until you use it , the compiler will not replace it with real (function / class) thing. You can't place it in dll. the only way is to provide it in header file. If you want to hide the implementation, consider using class hierarchy (runtime polymorphism)